# Combining critical speeds for a shaft of variable cross-section

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics, vibration

I am looking to determine the critical speed for a shaft with universal joints at each end, where the halves are joined by telescoping profile members. I can calculate the critical speed of each member individually, but I'm running into problems determining how to combine these numbers to get a critical speed for the whole assembly.

The shafts do operate at variable lengths, but I can prescribe the maximum length, so I will know the configuration at the worst-case scenario. The shaft can be divided into 3 sections, one with the inner member, one where the inner and outer member overlap, and one with the outer member. I have lengths and area moments of inertia for each cross-section, so I could calculate individual critical speeds, but I can't assume these simply combine linearly since the deformation of one section will contribute to the next.

I have tried some calculations using the Dunkerley equation -

$$\frac{1}{\omega^2}=\frac{1}{\omega_1^2}+\frac{1}{\omega_2^2}+\frac{1}{\omega_3^2}$$

but the numbers I got didn't seem to square with my experience in reality. Is this the correct way to do this, in which case I should look at other factors to address my vibration concerns with these shafts? Or is there another way to combine the three critical speeds to obtain a max speed for the whole shaft? (Note also that I don't need an exact answer necessarily - if there is a straightforward way that will give a decent estimate or the form of an equation, I can use existing data and experience to improve that estimate.)